# Show 1 to N on the terminal

Tags: command-line

I am looking for simple thing just, **foo 8** will shows this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

PS: I am looking just for command line. I know how to create that by using `for` on the bash

Comment: Are you saying you know the `seq` command (or brace expansion `{1..N}`) and are looking for something else?

Comment: No I say I know how show them via wrting a bash file. But I do not know there is 'seq' command.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To print a sequence of number the command 'seq' is your friend

```
seq 8
```

Comment: Also, `seq 5 10` prints `5 6 7 8 9 10`, and `seq 8 16 2` prints `8 10 12 14 16` (increments by 2 each step)

Comment: @professorfish FOr the second, it's `seq 8 2 16`, with the increment between first and last. `seq 8 16 2` prints nothing. (I always get it wrong too.)

Comment: `seq` is widely available in many Unices, and is part of `coreutils` in Linux, but it's [not POSIX and not portable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2102364/1157100).

Answer (score 16):

`{1..8}` will give you a simple argument range in Bash.

If you need that line by line, I'd suggest feeding that to something like printf:

```
$ printf '%d\n' {1..8}
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Comment: in here if 8 is a parameter. what I should write ? I mean: printf '%d\n' {0..a} ? thanks.

Comment: I try $a and ${a} and ...

Comment: @lion You have to re-evaluate the line because Bash won't expand. It becomes something like `n=5; printf '%d\n' $(eval echo {0..$n})`

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `echo` command with brace expansion

```
echo -e "\n"{1..8}

1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8
```

If you don't want the initial newline, you can use one of the below commands.

```
echo -e "\n"{1..8}|tail -n8

echo -e "\n"{1..8}|grep .

echo -e "\n"{1..8}|grep [0-9]

echo -e "\n"{1..8}|sed 1d
```

Comment: Just a heads up, the output starts with a newline, which may need to be trimmed out (perhaps with `tail`?) if you use the generated list of numbers in a script.

Comment: @IQAndreas I have made a edit and added all commands I could think of to remove the newline.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you can get it with simplest way as follows:

```
$ echo {1..8} | tr ' ' '\n'
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

OR:

```
$ for ((i=1 ; i<=8 ; i++)) do echo $i ; done;
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

*8 can be replaced by your 'N' positive integer!*

Answer (score 4):

You could use this simple `for` command,

```
$ for i in {1..8}; do echo $i; done
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Through awk,

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<=8;i++) {print i;}}'
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Comment: The OP specified: **I know how to create that by for on the bash**.  Use `while` to bring something new.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu added awk command.

Comment: It is still using `for` :)

Comment: OMG, i think he doesn't mean the awk for command.

Comment: And also I think he doesn't mean such a long command... WOE to use `bla bla bla ... print i ... bla bla` when you can only use only `printf '%d\n' {1..8}`?